# Actualizar campo MYsql con medidas

Tags: mysql, sql

Buenas noches a todos.

Tengo una tabla en MySQL de este estilo.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `evolucion_estatura` (
`ID` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Edad` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Estatura_Metros` DECIMAL(65,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Estatura_Pies` VARCHAR(800) NOT NULL DEFAULT '-',
PRIMARY KEY(`ID`)) ENGINE INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1_general_ci;
```

Me gustaria saber como puedo actualizar el campo `Estatura_Pies` para que sea solamente la estatura con los pies y pulgadas.

Comment: Hola. Disculpa, no es clara tu pregunta. ¿Cómo está ahora y cómo quieres que esté? Qué problema tiene al ser VARCHAR? O es que los datos están en algún formato raro?

Comment: Lo tengo en VARCHAR debido a que me interesa convertir de CM a pies con pulgadas (de ahi que lo tenga en este tipo de dato). He estado viendo este [enlace] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32606301/mysql-convert-height-format-from-centimeters-to-feet-inches) en el que se hacia esta consulta para convertirlo de CM a Pies con pulgadas: `select floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) as feet, (height_cm - floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) * 12 * 2.54) / 2.54 as inches`

Comment: De lo que me gustaria usar es la consulta `select floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) as feet, (height_cm - floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) * 12 * 2.54) / 2.54 as inches` pero para actualizar el campo `Estatura_Pies` con la consulta `select floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) as feet, (height_cm - floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) * 12 * 2.54) / 2.54 as inches`.

Answer (score 0):

Probá agregando esto `Estatura_Pies DECIMAL(65,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT (Estatura_Metros * 3.28084)`

Te quedaría así el código completo

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `evolucion_estatura` (
`ID` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`Edad` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Estatura_Metros` DECIMAL(65,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`Estatura_Pies` DECIMAL(65,2) UNSIGNED NOT NULL DEFAULT (`Estatura_Metros` * 3.28084),
PRIMARY KEY(`ID`)) ENGINE INNODB DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1_general_ci;
```

Recordá no pasarle ningún valor a Estatura_Pies al momento de usar Insert automáticamente se guardarán los metros transformados a pies.

Comment: He intentado crear la tabla, pero no me deja hacerlo debido al campo `Estatura_Pies`. He estado viendo una cosa en la pagina que es una consulta que te da directamente los CM a la medida en pies con pulgadas `select floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) as feet, (height_cm - floor(height_cm / (2.54 * 12)) * 12 * 2.54) / 2.54 as inches` (me gustaria usarlo en la actualizacion y no se como)